# Django : "No installed app with label 'flatpages'." with django-markdown

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add a feature to my Django website that implements articles written with a bit of markdown by an admin.

I installed django-markdown, and followed this tutorial :
http://pythonhosted.org/django-markdown/

I makemigrations/migrate and runserver and I succeed to reach my website, but when I try to access to the admin interface I get an issue saying :
`No installed app with label 'flatpages'.`

Here is the content of my requirements.txt :

```
Django==1.7.5
django-markdown==0.8.4
Markdown==2.6
wheel==0.24.0
```

I assume it is the flatpages from the django_markdown module.
I tried some things, as adding 'flatpages' to INSTALLED_APPS. but this doesn't fix the problem (and 'django_markdown' is already in it).
I'm not experienced enough with django to understand what happens in my project and I need some help to understand the issue.
Could anyone help me, Please?

#### Here are some additionnal informations and files that could be useful :

**The error :**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/

Django Version: 1.7.5
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_markdown',
 'main')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/vmonteco/Envs/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/vmonteco/Envs/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in wrapper
  227.                 return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vmonteco/Envs/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vmonteco/Envs/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vmonteco/Envs/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  206.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vmonteco/Envs/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vmonteco/Envs/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in index
  401.                             'name': apps.get_app_config(app_label).verbose_name,
File "/home/vmonteco/Envs/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py" in get_app_config
  150.             raise LookupError("No installed app with label '%s'." % app_label)

Exception Type: LookupError at /admin/
Exception Value: No installed app with label 'flatpages'.
```

**hypnose/settings.py :**

```
"""
Django settings for hypnose project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Template dirs.
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
]

# Static dirs.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

#Email settings

#markdown flatpages
# import django_markdown
MARKDOWN_EDITOR_SKIN = 'simple'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_markdown',
    # 'django.contrib.flatpages',
    #'django_markdown.flatpages',
    'main',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'hypnose.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'hypnose.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**hypnose/urls.py :**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django_markdown import flatpages

admin.autodiscover()
flatpages.register()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url('^markdown/', include('django_markdown.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('main.urls')),
)
```

**main/admin.py :**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from main.models import Article
from django_markdown.admin import MarkdownModelAdmin

admin.site.register(Article, MarkdownModelAdmin)
```

**main/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django_markdown.models import MarkdownField
from django_markdown.widgets import MarkdownWidget
from django import forms
from django.forms.widgets import *

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    # I just changed content from forms.CharField to MarkdownField
    # because this field wasn't appearing in
    # my admin pannel.
    # content = forms.CharField(required = False, widget=MarkdownWidget())
    content = MarkdownField(null = True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now = False, verbose_name = "Date de parution")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return (u"%s" % (self.title,))

    def __str__(self):
        return ("%s" % (self.title,))
```

What could it be, and what could I do?
Thank you for your help. :)

EDIT:
Problem solved, but to interpret the markdown in my templates I also had to install django-markdown-deux :
https://github.com/trentm/django-markdown-deux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The flatpages app is [part of Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/flatpages/). You need to properly install it. From the official installation docs:

> To install the flatpages app, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Install the sites framework by adding `'django.contrib.sites'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting, if it's not already in there.
>
> Also make sure you've correctly set `SITE_ID` to the `ID` of the site the settings file represents. This will usually be `1` (i.e. `SITE_ID = 1`, but if you're using the sites framework to manage multiple sites, it could be the ID of a different site.
>
> 2. Add `'django.contrib.flatpages'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. Then either:
>
>    (a) Add an entry in your URLconf. For example:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^pages/', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
)
```

> or (b) Add `'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware'` to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting.
>
> 3. Run the command `manage.py migrate`.

Comment: I assumed flatpages was also a part of the django-markdown module, is django.contrib.flatpages the same thing than django_markdown.flatpages? With the same purpose?
(perhaps django_markdown.flatpages is just a tool to add markdown to flatpages?)
Perhaps django_markdown.flatpages isn't necessary to use markdown with other classes (as my Article class).
Anyway your answer fixed my issue (even if there is still a problem with the markdown which isn't interpreted but I think that is something else :) )
Thank you!

Comment: I've honestly never used django_markdown.flatpages, so I'm not sure what purpose it serves. I'm glad my answer helped you clear things up!

Comment: I think that's it, I just looked in their github and this is the docstring of flatpages.py : """ Support markdown by Django Flatpages admin. """ :)

More at https://github.com/klen/django_markdown and https://github.com/klen/django_markdown/blob/develop/django_markdown/flatpages.py

Comment: Well, there you go! Now we know :-)